# What's the meaning of the following parameters of the coreference in Corenlp?

Tags: python, parameters, nlp, stanford-nlp

What's the meaning of the following parameters of the coreference in Corenlp: "type", "number", "headIndex", "position"?
Here is an example of the output when using the coreference in corenlp:
{'id': 67, 'text': 'a whole input sentence', 'type': 'NOMINAL', 'number': 'SINGULAR', 'gender': 'UNKNOWN', 'animacy': 'INANIMATE', 'startIndex': 23, 'endIndex': 27, 'headIndex': 26, 'sentNum': 9, 'position': [9, 5], 'isRepresentativeMention': True}

Comment: Surely this is a question for the package documentation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.